# how to save custom view state in android studio

Tags: android, state, android-room, android-custom-view

I'm developing an application which has drawing functionality. I want to save my drawing in the room database with the view(whatever users draw). It should be restored when the user clicks on his drawing from their history.

```
if (stateBundleFromDb!=null){
   super.onCreate(stateBundleFromDb)
   mySavedState = stateBundleFromDb
}else{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   mySavedState = savedInstanceState
}
```

When I click one of the history items I get `stateBundleFromDb` but when I open the activity directly then I get `savedInstanceState`.

**Is there any possible way to save view state in local storage?**

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to have a future; don't abuse `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: okay, thanks @MartinZeitler
can you tell me how should i save drawing view?

Comment: I'd just safe it into a file and save the path to the file into Room DB... else you might only exceed the limitations of `Bundle`, when drawing on a large tablet, with many details.

Comment: We need to know some more about how the drawings are created. If you are producing vector output then you could store that data in a structured format to be restored so the user can edit. Otherwise a raster format is the way to go. Also, try to think about the view and the state separately (the view is never stored, only the state). That might help when negotiating the logic.

Comment: okay @MichaelLundie thanks, can you tell how can i save that data in a structured format?

Comment: @Jerry Your're welcome. You will need to find a way to parse the object instance (or instances) that represents the image (that the user is creating) into a format such as SVG (likely your best option). Your "save state"/output solution depends on your input implementation. If this was my first time doing a project like this, I might attempt to save output as raster first (the easier option) and then attempt vector output once everything is working. It really depends on what your intended project outcomes are.